# Efficient join technique for huger master table and even huger permission table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, data-synchronization

I am working on a concept for database synchronization recently. 
The scenario is as follows:

- there is a master table "Items" with 1M+ rows in it

  ```
      CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item](
          [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
          [Title] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
          [Modified] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT [PK_Item] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
  ```
- we want to sync data to a client in a very flexible way - so we are playing around with a "Items_sync" table, that contains an entry for every user and every item they should download during a sync process.

  ```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item_syncfilter](
      [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [ItemId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
      [Modified] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
      [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
      [UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Item_syncfilter] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
  ```

Now what makes this a bit complicated is the following:
There are numerous reasons, why a particular user may get the permission to download a particular row (he is added to the contributors group, he is added to the administrators group, an item is directly assigned to him/her).
Thus, there may be multiple rows for the same user for a single item stating that she is allowed to download that item.

Also, the sync process needs to work incrementally.
Meaning: 
 * If user Andrew has access to item A, and it is modified, next time he syncs he should receive the newest version
 * Is user Andrew did not have access to item A, but then he is added to the administrators group (=> gets a corresponding Item_sync entry) he should download the item the next time he syncs.
 * If Andrew had already synced item A and is added to the administrators group, nothing should be synced.

Now what we came up with up until now is the following query:

```
declare @userid bigint;
declare @date datetime2(7);
set @date = '2018-05-02 13:00:00.0000000';
set @userid = 5;

select i.*, 0 as Toombstoned from item i
where 
-- clause 1: get all modified items where there exists at least one non-deleted sync row
(i.modified >= @date
    -- and there exists at least one non-deleted syncfilter
    and exists (select id from item_syncfilter where itemid = i.id and userid = @userid and isdeleted = 0))
-- clause 2: get all items, which were not modified, but their sync rows are newer (toombstoned or not)
or (i.modified <  @date
    -- and there is at least one younger, non-deleted syncfilter (permission was added to user)
    and exists (select id from item_syncfilter where itemid = i.id and userid = @userid and isdeleted = 0 and modified >  @date)
    -- make sure this item was not already synced by an older valid and non-deleted filter
    and not exists (select id from item_syncfilter where itemid = i.id and userid = @userid and isdeleted = 0 and modified <  @date))

union all
select i.*, 1 as Toombstoned from item i
where 
-- clause 3: get all toombstoned items
--                  - where no non-deleted syncfilter exists
--                  - and there is a deleted sync filter younger than "date"
(not exists (select id from item_syncfilter where itemid = i.id and userid = @userid and isdeleted = 0)
    and exists (select id from item_syncfilter where itemid = i.id and userid = @userid and isdeleted = 1 and modified >  @date))
```

However this performs quite bad due to the 5 usages of "exists": i.e. for 1 million rows in the main table, the query runs for 5 seconds and the STATISTICS IO output shows a looooot of reads, even if the query only returns a small subset of data.

Can you give me any hint how we could improve this query dramatically?

**UPDATE**
Thanks for your responses.
The following sql snippet shows 
* the complete table schema
* including indexes that I use
* and some testdata which showcases how the query works

```
-- ########################
-- ## Sync Item
-- ########################

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Modified] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Item] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Item] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Item_Id]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [Id]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Item] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Item_Modified]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [Modified]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ItemModified] ON [dbo].[Item]
(
    [Modified] DESC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


-- ########################
-- ## sync filter
-- ########################

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item_syncfilter](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Modified] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Item_syncfilter] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Item_syncfilter_Modified]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [Modified]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Item_syncfilter_IsDeleted]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsDeleted]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Item_syncfilter_UserId]  DEFAULT (CONVERT([int],((20)+(1))*rand())) FOR [UserId]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SyncItemModified] ON [dbo].[Item_syncfilter]
(
    [UserId] ASC,
    [ItemId] ASC,
    [IsDeleted] ASC,
    [Modified] DESC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SyncItemItemId] ON [dbo].[Item_syncfilter]
(
    [ItemId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


-- ########################
-- ## TestData
-- ########################

INSERT [dbo].[Item] ([Id], [Title], [Modified]) VALUES (N'a14ae781-b595-4fa8-942f-3abf8d848bdf', N'1 new deleted, 1 old still valid  NOTINSYNC', CAST(N'2018-05-01T14:10:25.8400000' AS DateTime2))
INSERT [dbo].[Item] ([Id], [Title], [Modified]) VALUES (N'45b71309-49d9-4457-a784-52dcc1331ec2', N'Modified and all filters new', CAST(N'2018-05-03T06:33:04.7200000' AS DateTime2))
INSERT [dbo].[Item] ([Id], [Title], [Modified]) VALUES (N'cf01ebde-7f11-4bad-a32c-54caa6fca14b', N'No new filter NOTINSYNC', CAST(N'2018-05-01T14:10:11.0833333' AS DateTime2))
INSERT [dbo].[Item] ([Id], [Title], [Modified]) VALUES (N'80fc71ff-e984-4dae-bdf1-98e02d27c926', N'All deleted', CAST(N'2018-05-02T14:09:48.6200000' AS DateTime2))
INSERT [dbo].[Item] ([Id], [Title], [Modified]) VALUES (N'a5fa6d29-5c2b-4edb-8390-aeec44232368', N'Modified', CAST(N'2018-05-02T14:09:48.6200000' AS DateTime2))
INSERT [dbo].[Item] ([Id], [Title], [Modified]) VALUES (N'5995209d-c571-40b8-9ff6-b650add6ffbf', N'Some filters new NOTINSYNC', CAST(N'2018-05-01T14:10:04.2900000' AS DateTime2))
INSERT [dbo].[Item] ([Id], [Title], [Modified]) VALUES (N'd79a3967-780c-46e3-b1ec-e6038214e711', N'All filters new', CAST(N'2018-05-01T14:10:04.2900000' AS DateTime2))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] ([Id], [ItemId], [Modified], [IsDeleted], [UserId]) VALUES (1, N'a5fa6d29-5c2b-4edb-8390-aeec44232368', CAST(N'2018-05-01T14:13:30.5000000' AS DateTime2), 0, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] ([Id], [ItemId], [Modified], [IsDeleted], [UserId]) VALUES (2, N'a5fa6d29-5c2b-4edb-8390-aeec44232368', CAST(N'2018-05-01T14:13:37.8133333' AS DateTime2), 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] ([Id], [ItemId], [Modified], [IsDeleted], [UserId]) VALUES (3, N'd79a3967-780c-46e3-b1ec-e6038214e711', CAST(N'2018-05-02T16:15:04.5933333' AS DateTime2), 0, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] ([Id], [ItemId], [Modified], [IsDeleted], [UserId]) VALUES (4, N'd79a3967-780c-46e3-b1ec-e6038214e711', CAST(N'2018-05-02T16:15:07.1266667' AS DateTime2), 0, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] ([Id], [ItemId], [Modified], [IsDeleted], [UserId]) VALUES (5, N'a14ae781-b595-4fa8-942f-3abf8d848bdf', CAST(N'2018-05-01T14:13:37.8133333' AS DateTime2), 0, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] ([Id], [ItemId], [Modified], [IsDeleted], [UserId]) VALUES (6, N'a14ae781-b595-4fa8-942f-3abf8d848bdf', CAST(N'2018-05-02T14:15:31.7666667' AS DateTime2), 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] ([Id], [ItemId], [Modified], [IsDeleted], [UserId]) VALUES (7, N'cf01ebde-7f11-4bad-a32c-54caa6fca14b', CAST(N'2018-05-01T14:13:37.8133333' AS DateTime2), 0, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] ([Id], [ItemId], [Modified], [IsDeleted], [UserId]) VALUES (8, N'cf01ebde-7f11-4bad-a32c-54caa6fca14b', CAST(N'2018-05-01T14:13:37.8133333' AS DateTime2), 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] ([Id], [ItemId], [Modified], [IsDeleted], [UserId]) VALUES (9, N'80fc71ff-e984-4dae-bdf1-98e02d27c926', CAST(N'2018-05-01T14:13:37.8133333' AS DateTime2), 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] ([Id], [ItemId], [Modified], [IsDeleted], [UserId]) VALUES (10, N'80fc71ff-e984-4dae-bdf1-98e02d27c926', CAST(N'2018-04-30T14:13:37.8133333' AS DateTime2), 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] ([Id], [ItemId], [Modified], [IsDeleted], [UserId]) VALUES (11, N'5995209d-c571-40b8-9ff6-b650add6ffbf', CAST(N'2018-04-30T14:13:37.8133333' AS DateTime2), 0, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] ([Id], [ItemId], [Modified], [IsDeleted], [UserId]) VALUES (12, N'5995209d-c571-40b8-9ff6-b650add6ffbf', CAST(N'2018-05-02T16:39:20.5066667' AS DateTime2), 0, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] ([Id], [ItemId], [Modified], [IsDeleted], [UserId]) VALUES (13, N'5995209d-c571-40b8-9ff6-b650add6ffbf', CAST(N'2018-05-02T16:39:21.7066667' AS DateTime2), 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] ([Id], [ItemId], [Modified], [IsDeleted], [UserId]) VALUES (14, N'45b71309-49d9-4457-a784-52dcc1331ec2', CAST(N'2018-05-03T06:33:34.7900000' AS DateTime2), 0, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] ([Id], [ItemId], [Modified], [IsDeleted], [UserId]) VALUES (15, N'45b71309-49d9-4457-a784-52dcc1331ec2', CAST(N'2018-05-03T06:33:38.0300000' AS DateTime2), 1, 1)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] OFF
```

To generate the testdata I used:

```
   -- ## Create many items items
   DECLARE @startnum INT=1;
   DECLARE @endnum INT=5000;

   WITH gen AS (
       SELECT @startnum AS num
       UNION ALL
       SELECT num+1 FROM gen WHERE num+1<=@endnum
   ) 

   insert into [Item] ([Id], [Title], [Modified])
   (SELECT newId() as [Id]
         ,[Title]  + ' -#'+ CONVERT(varchar(1000), n.num) as [Title]
         ,[Modified]
     FROM [Item]
     cross join gen as n)
   option (maxrecursion 10000);

   select count(*) as item_count from item;

   -- ## generate syncfilter rows for 10 users
   set @startNum = 1;
   set @endNum = 10;

   WITH gen AS (
       SELECT @startnum AS num
       UNION ALL
       SELECT num+1 FROM gen WHERE num+1<=@endnum
   )    

    insert into item_syncfilter ([ItemId],[Modified],[IsDeleted],[UserId])
    (select i.[Id], DATEADD(month, -6, i.[Modified]), 0 as IsDeleted, n.num as [Userid] from item i 
       left outer join item_syncfilter s on s.itemid = i.id
         cross join gen as n
       where s.id is null)
    option (maxrecursion 10000);

    select count(*) item_syncfilter_count from Item_syncfilter;
```

this creates 35K items and 350K syncfilte rows

the statistics IO output is

```
(15003 rows affected)
Table 'Item_syncfilter'. Scan count 35013, logical reads 105648, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Item'. Scan count 1, logical reads 610, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(21 rows affected)

(1 row affected)
```

You can download the execution plan from [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhVbOiFFuzx_1yFHFWnUwEks1e_f)

Comment: Can you paste the actual execution plan [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)? Seems like you have bad estimates but that could be for a lot of reasons. Also, you didn't specify if there are any indexes on these two tables.

Comment: Try creating index on column ItemId and modified in table Item_syncfilter

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I went along looked at the execution plan of the separate sub-clauses of the query.

For clause 3 (finding tombstoned items), the execution plan showed that the following index would improve the performance:

```
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SyncItemDeletedItems] ON [dbo].[Item_syncfilter] 
    (
        [IsDeleted],
        [UserId],
        [Modified])
    INCLUDE ([ItemId])
```

Running only clause 3 of the query with "statistics IO on":

```
    set statistics io on

    declare @userid bigint;
    declare @date datetime2(7);
    set @date = '2018-05-02 13:00:00.0000000';
    set @userid = 5;

    select i.*, 1 as Toombstoned from item i
    where 
    -- clause 3: get all toombstoned items
    --                  - where no non-deleted syncfilter exists
    --                  - and there is a deleted sync filter younger than "date"
    (not exists (select id from item_syncfilter where itemid = i.id and userid = @userid and isdeleted = 0)
        and exists (select id from item_syncfilter where itemid = i.id and userid = @userid and isdeleted = 1 and modified >  @date))
```

shows before:

```
  (0 rows affected)
  Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
  Table 'Item_syncfilter'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1433, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

  (1 row affected)
```

after:

```
  (0 rows affected)
  Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
  Table 'Item_syncfilter'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

  (1 row affected)
```

... so this greatly reduces the number of logical reads!

For clause 1 and 2, it was more interesting. If run separately, they performed quite well, but combined, they resulted in a terrible execution plan:

```
    set statistics io on

    declare @userid bigint;
    declare @date datetime2(7);
    set @date = '2018-05-02 13:00:00.0000000';
    set @userid = 5;

    select i.*, 0 as Toombstoned from item i
    where 
    -- clause 1: get all modified items where there exists at least one non-deleted sync row
    (i.modified >= @date
        -- and there exists at least one non-deleted syncfilter
        and exists (select id from item_syncfilter where itemid = i.id and userid = @userid and isdeleted = 0))
    -- clause 2: get all items, which were not modified, but their sync rows are newer (toombstoned or not)
    or (i.modified <  @date
        -- and there is at least one younger, non-deleted syncfilter (permission was added to user)
        and exists (select id from item_syncfilter where itemid = i.id and userid = @userid and isdeleted = 0 and modified >  @date)
        -- make sure this item was not already synced by an older valid and non-deleted filter
        and not exists (select id from item_syncfilter where itemid = i.id and userid = @userid and isdeleted = 0 and modified <  @date))
```

Returns

```
    (0 rows affected)
    Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
    Table 'Item_syncfilter'. Scan count 229376, logical reads 688128, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
    Table 'Item'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3980, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

    (1 row affected)
```

The reason is the following execution step in the execution plan:

[image]

So as you can see, sql server scans the clustered index for items where the modified date is >= @date OR < @date, which more or less returns the whole table -> thus, those many reads

So what I did was to simply split the two clauses, which were combined using "OR" into two separate queries which are just combined using UNION ALL:

```
    set statistics io on

    declare @userid bigint;
    declare @date datetime2(7);
    set @date = '2018-05-02 13:00:00.0000000';
    set @userid = 5;

    select i.*, 0 as Toombstoned from item i
    where 
    -- clause 1: get all modified items where there exists at least one non-deleted sync row
    (i.modified >= @date
        -- and there exists at least one non-deleted syncfilter
        and exists (select id from item_syncfilter where itemid = i.id and userid = @userid and isdeleted = 0))

    -- clause 2: get all items, which were not modified, but their sync rows are newer (toombstoned or not)
    union all
    select i.*, 0 as Toombstoned from item i
        where i.modified <  @date
        -- and there is at least one younger, non-deleted syncfilter (permission was added to user)
        and exists (select id from item_syncfilter where itemid = i.id and userid = @userid and isdeleted = 0 and modified >  @date)
        -- make sure this item was not already synced by an older valid and non-deleted filter
        and not exists (select id from item_syncfilter where itemid = i.id and userid = @userid and isdeleted = 0 and modified <  @date)
```

which interestingly yields the following statistics

```
    (0 rows affected)
    Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
    Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
    Table 'Item_syncfilter'. Scan count 3, logical reads 12, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
    Table 'Item'. Scan count 2, logical reads 8, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

    (1 row affected)
```

=> so from 229376 down to 3, from 688128 down to 12, etc.
This is a huge gain!